# Add no duplicates to List of supperclass (check for equality with subclasses)

Tags: java, inheritance, comparison

I have a `List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();` I add two different Items to, both subclasses  of `Item`: `PortableItem` and `SceneryItem`.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<item> {
    public String id;
    public String desc;

    ...

    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return getId().compareTo(o.getId());
    }  
}
```

Now I would like to detect Items with duplicate `ID`s before adding a new one to my List.

```
    PortableItem a = new PortableItem("a");
    SceneryItem b  = new SceneryItem("a");
    items.add(a);
    items.contains(b);
```

Returns false. How can I change that behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an `equals` method that compared on id, be default an `Object` equals another when they are `==` - i.e. the same instance. This isn't what you want.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

    public String id;
    public String desc;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return getId().compareTo(o.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Item other = (Item) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is really good practice anyway given your `compareTo` method and the requirement that is is **consistent with equals** - now `a.equals(b)` will return true if they have the same `id`.

As you now have an `equals` method you **have to have** a `hashCode()` method, again the consistent with equals requirement.

Note that if you override the `equals` method in a superclass this obviously won't work unless you use a call to `return super.equals` at the end.

Now, using a `List` the `contains` method is guaranteed O(n) - this is *very slow*. I would recommend using a `Set` where `contains` is guaranteed O(1). If you need to maintain order use a `LinkedHashSet` or even better a `TreeSet` which will use your `compareTo` method to order items automagically.

You can always turn the thing into a `List` afterwards with one O(n) call anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in the base class to compare by ID.
`compareTo()` is only used for sorting.

Comment: Not `getHashCode()`, just `hashCode()`.

Comment: @bmorris591: Fixed; I'm too used to C#.